# Why does my user_pool_domain always need to be replaced?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I get the following whenever I run terraform plan/apply and I don't know why this is saying it always needs to be replaced. The ACM is managed at the root of my project, and then the ARN is passed to my Cognito module.

```
# module.cognito["users"].aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.main must be replaced
+/- resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_domain" "main" {
      ~ certificate_arn             = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:123456789:certificate/bc955b8a-45c6-4003-1b2a-5z66333fef275" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
    }
```

## Update - add module call and DNS file for clarity

#### cognito.tf (root of the project)

```
module "cognito" {
  source = "../modules/cognito"

  for_each = var.cognito_userpools

  cognito_name_prefix                             = "${try(each.value.name_prefix, local.name_prefix)}-${each.key}"
  cognito_domain_name                             = try("${each.value.domain_prefix}.${local.dns_address}", null)
  cognito_https_acm_arn                           = try(aws_acm_certificate.cognito_https_cert[each.key].arn, null)
  hosted_zone_id                                  = try(aws_route53_zone.public_hosted_zone.id, null)
  cognito_callback_urls                           = each.value.callback_urls
  cognito_logout_urls                             = each.value.logout_urls
  cognito_sms_external_id                         = each.value.sms_external_id
  cognito_userpool_schemas                        = each.value.userpool_schemas
  cognito_mfa_configuration                       = try(each.value.mfa_configuration, "ON")
  cognito_enable_software_token_mfa_configuration = try(each.value.enable_software_token_mfa_configuration, true)
  cognito_userpool_groups                         = try(each.value.groups, [])
  tags                                            = local.default_tags
}
```

#### acm.tf (root of the project)

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cognito_https_cert" {
  for_each                  = var.cognito_userpools
  provider                  = aws.us-east-1
  domain_name               = "${each.value.domain_prefix}.${local.dns_address}"
  subject_alternative_names = ["*.${each.value.domain_prefix}.${local.dns_address}"]

  validation_method = "DNS"

  tags = local.default_tags

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

#### modules/cognito/dns.tf

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_domain" "main" {
  domain          = var.cognito_domain_name
  certificate_arn = var.cognito_https_acm_arn
  user_pool_id    = aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.id
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cognito_record" {
  name            = aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.main.domain
  type            = "A"
  zone_id         = var.hosted_zone_id
  allow_overwrite = true

  alias {
    evaluate_target_health = false
    name                   = aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.main.cloudfront_distribution_arn
    # NOTE: This zone_id is fixed
    zone_id = "Z2FDTNDATAQYW2"
  }
}
```

#### Update 2

Upon further investigation tag updates were causing the arn not to be known until after apply, this isn’t ideal and only a problem with cognito custom domains - I don’t have the same issue with API Gateway custom domains for example. Does anyone have any idea on a workaround rather than relying on ignoring tag updates as a lifecycle meta argument?

Comment: We need to see the rest of the module call and possibly the module code as well.

Comment: Hey, have updated with the appropriate files

Comment: Is this variable `var.cognito_https_acm_arn` changing value between plan/apply actions for some reason?

Comment: Ah, ok, so you are passing a certificate ARN for each of the certificates created while the user pool domain is expecting only one value.

Comment: Yeah so a certificate is created for each userpool, then the corresponding ARN is passed as a variable to the module for that respective userpool which then uses it to configure a custom domain for itself.

The certificate is not being flagged as changing, my thoughts are that Terraform is marking the value as not known so within the module it thinks it needs to re-create the domain, but that behavior doesn't fit with another module I've created for an API where I use the same pattern with no issues.

Comment: Is that the only change Terraform is proposing to make? I'd expect to also see a proposal to replace some of the `aws_acm_certificate.cognito_https_cert` instances -- or to take _some_ action against them, at least -- thereby causing the `arn` to be unknown when you pass it in to the module.

Comment: Just tags, i wouldn't of thought that would cause an arn not to known though? The resource already exists and it just states update-in-place then tags for the acm cert

Comment: tag updates are the issue, have amended my question - although this is not an issue with other custom domain resources like API gateway.